# How to make an extends object turn to its super object

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism

is there a design pattern that I can make an object to have some kind of state where he starts as an extended object, but after some time turn back to its super.

For example - partial file inherits from a file and after its completed it goes to be a file.

Comment: No. But you can design the state of the class itself to mimic this behavior. Read up on the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

Comment: After some time? Override all methods from super checking for your condition, if the condition is met, just call super.foo(), otherwise do what the implementation should do at start

Comment: Your `PartialFile` **is already** a `File`... What would (somewhat)  make more sense is to say that your `PartialFile` should become a `CompleteFile` and both types inherit `File`.

Comment: As WATTO Studios says, the question is most likely flawed. The OP most likely does not want to "mutate" to superclass, but just use it as its superclass.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no type mutation in Java (and to be fair I can't think of any modern language having it).

What you may do, but it's clearly not exactly the same :

- using a constructor taking your object as a parameter to build a new object in a different class (just like you can do `new Float(new Double(2));`). Note that this doesn't change the initial object so you have to assign again the variable(s) holding it.
- add a `type` variable, based on an `enum`, indicating what's the nature of the object. For most purposes it's enough (and will save you from building an heavy type hierarchy).

Now, do you **need** type mutation ? If you just need to handle your object as if it was a direct instance of its superclass, you can do it already. The main difference with type mutation is that you call the overridden methods but that's normally fine if the type hierarchy was correctly designed.

And supposing I'd design a PartialFile class (supposing the name properly defines what it is), instead of using inheritance I would have used composition : I would have made a decorative class whose instance would have had a variable `private File sourceFile`.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about type mutation, but simply got his/her question wrongly explained.

Answer (score 1):

This question is flawed - an extended `Object` is always an instance of its super class.

In your example, the following is valid...

```
public class PartialFile extends File{
    // methods
    }

PartialFile partFile = new PartialFile();

// do operations on partFile 

File file = partFile;

// do operations on file
```

Because `PartialFile` extends `File`, you don't really need to 'turn it into its super class' - it already is an instance of the super class.

You can think of the `PartialFile` object as being a `PartialFile`, a `File`, an `Object`, and any other classes that it extends, all at the same time. You don't need to turn it between these different class types - just use it directly. For the above code, if you want to call the `File.rename()` method, both the following statements will do the same thing...

```
partFile.rename();
file.rename();
```

You don't need to change the `partFile` into a `file` to use the methods of the `File` object - just use them directly, as the Java VM knows that a `PartialFile` is also a `File`.

You can't really change a sub-type to be its super type - the Java VM will always know what type it really is - but you can trick it. If you use the following code...

```
PartialFile partFile = new PartialFile();
// do operations on partFile 

File file = partFile;
// do operations on file
```

and then only every use `file` instead of `partFile`, you won't be able to use any of the `PartialFile` methods on it. It kinda disguises that its a `PartialFile`, but it doesn't actually convert it.

If you do something like this...

```
public File createFile(){
    PartialFile partFile = new PartialFile();
    // operations on partFile
    return partFile;
}

File file = createFile();
// operations on file
```

You can create and use a `PartialFile` in the method, but when you're finished you return it as a simple `File`. Whenever you refer to this object from now on, the Java VM will pretend that its a `File`. However, technically it will always be a `PartialFile`, and it doesn't stop you casting it back into a `PartialFile` if you want to, like so...

```
PartialFile partFile = (PartialFile)file;
// operations on partFile
```

So its just a disguise.

Comment: I want it to be only the super-class and not the sub-class.

Comment: You can't change a sub-type into a super-type, but you can 'trick' the Java VM into thinking its only the super-type - see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass is already an instance of its superclass, so you can just cast it to its superclass

```
class PartialFile extends File {
// Code...
}

PartialFile partialFile;
// Code...
File file = (File) partialFile;
```

Comment: You don't need to cast in that case. `File file = partialFile;` would work to. But `file` would still be a `PartialFile`...

Comment: That won't change the behaviour at all.

Comment: Did the OP ask about behavior change? And anyway what behavior change do you expect? A subclass already behaves like the superclass (plus extra behavior).

Comment: Keep in mind that a subclass can also override/replace behavior in the parent class.  A possible reason to want to mutate it to the superclass would be to use that parent behavior.  Still, this seems like a pretty atypical use case.  Assuming that, a one-off converter FileTransformer.convert(PartialFile in, File out).  So, yes, there can be "extra" behavior, but there can be lost behavior, too.

Comment: I understand that, but the OP didn't specify anywhere that he/she cares about the behavior change. First, the question is badly formulated. And second, IMHO, he just wants simple polymorphism and not actually mutate the child into the super. Still I don't see any reason my answer got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Use design pattern State and/or a Factory method.

You may still have to do some refactoring, as you would most likely need an Interface/abstract base class for the super.

Something like this:

```
class MySwitcher implements SuperInterface {

  private final SuperInterface super = new Super();

  private final SuperInterface subclass = new Subclass();

  private SuperInterface current = super; // Start in state "behaves as super"

  // Method from SuperInterface
  public MyResult doAction(final MyData d) {
    final MyResult res = current.doAction(d);
    current = setImplementationBasedOnResOfDoAction(res);
    return res;
  }

}
```